# Deleting NDF from file group completely?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want a script to delete NDF file from a file group completely without using "shrinkfile " command

Comment: NDF is actual data ,why you want to delete it

Comment: NDF files are just like MDF files, they contain data. LDF files are for log data. Do NOT delete NDF files!

Comment: @user3378165 it is not my homework ,, i didn't force u to answer me :)

Comment: @TheGameiswar and Eralper 
the for replying
the data already in the main server we want to delete it from the accessible users's server to force users to pay if they want to have old data (older than 6 months )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file can be removed from the database only if the file is empty.  Without `SHRINKFILE`, the implication is that the file must be the only file in a user-defined filegroup and you must first drop or move all the objects (or partitions) from the filegroup to a different file group.  The empty file can then be dropped with `ALTER DATABASE...REMOVE FILE`.

It seems your objective is to delete data older than 6 months.  It would be easier to just delete/truncate the data and not bother with files/filegroups at all.